# Get Json element Value If Some variable detected in Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi I have A json output as bellow :

```
. and so on
. 
.
    [vote_count] => 76
    [alternative_titles] => stdClass Object
        (
            [titles] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [iso_3166_1] => US
                            [title] => Basic Math
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [iso_3166_1] => CN
                            [title] => çˆ±çˆ±ä¸Šäº‘ç«¯
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

how do i can get The ***"Title" value, If "US" In "iso_3166_1"*** is detected ?

I try to solve it by my self, but my code did not work, here is my code:

```
<?php    
$json_tmdb  = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt1956620?api_key=31d2bb992c7bdcbfb98b554ccab12b88&append_to_response=alternative_titles';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_tmdb));

    if (in_array('US', $json_tmdb)) {
        echo "Match found";
        // echo title value
    }

    else
    {
    echo "Match not found";
    return false;
    } 
?>
```

Hope some one here can help me,thx q

Comment: Edited, sorry i am not to familiar with stackoverflow, but this is wonderful forum :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This :

```
function findKey($array,$k,$v)
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            findKey($value,$k,$v);
        }
        else
        {
            if($key == $k && $v == $value){
                echo "key = $k value = $value\n";
            }
       }
    }
}

$json_tmdb  = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt1956620?api_key=31d2bb992c7bdcbfb98b554ccab12b88&append_to_response=alternative_titles';
findKey(json_decode(file_get_contents($json_tmdb),true),'iso_3166_1','US');
```

Comment: HI Pulkit, It work actually, but i need to pass the 'iso_3166_1' key to Variable, when i try to put $mykey=$key; echo $mykey; , it give me an error, can you please tell me how to passed it to variable ?

Comment: I changed code accordingly in my answer, i hope this will help.

Comment: still same result, the output is twice for same data (one data) , here is the output "key = iso_3166_1 value = US key = iso_3166_1 value = US " it should be just one

Comment: you are getting values two times because in code json it is two times . If you open it url 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/tt1956620?api_key=31d2bb992c7bdcbfb98b554ccab12b88&append_to_response=alternative_titles' you will notice that same key value pair exists twice..

Comment: OMG, just Know it, actually i just need get "alternative_titles -> title" only , but all country using "iso_3166_1" Key, can you help me for displaying value only for "alternative_titles" only ?

Comment: you can replace last line by:  $json_arr = json_decode(file_get_contents($json_tmdb),true);  findKey($json_arr['alternative_titles'],'iso_3166_1','US');

Comment: You Are Awesome Pulkit, Thanks Q so much helping me out from this, It Really Work . . .